# boost::bind method with non constant arguments

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to bind a boost method that has an argument list, but I want to specify the value of the arguments when I emit the signal, not as a constant when binding.

```
boost::bind( &myClass::myMethod, this, _1 ) );
```

My understanding is the `_1` means to hold a place for an argument, but let me specify it at call time.  This gives me a compile error saying that `_1` an undeclared identifier and when I use a constant then specify an argument at call time, the constant is used.

The boost manual talks about doing this `_1` with functions (as opposed to methods) - is there a way to do this with methods?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What files are you including?

Comment: Your code seems ok. More context is needed. Please provide a complete minimal example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: [The Boost manual also talks about it with methods.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers) Your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot the namespace qualification- `_1` is an object, and it's lookup must be qualified.

Comment: Boost placeholders are in the global namespace. Other libraries put their placeholders in named namespaces, but boost doesn't.